# Android: Probleme use keyboard enter button say “Search” and handle its click?

Tags: java, android, search-engine, textedit

I want to add a search button on the keyboard input and the EditText and searches I proceeded as follows and I have them the following errors

```
recherche=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.recherche);

recherche.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

                    new DownloadTask().execute();                   
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**ERROR :** The type new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
 TextView.OnEditorActionListener.onEditorAction(TextView, int, KeyEvent)

**ERROR :** KeyEvent cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of my code:

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener enterListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
       if ((keyEvent != null && (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                   InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            bQServer.performClick();
        }
        return false;
    }
};

//etUserName.setOnEditorActionListener(enterListener);
etPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(enterListener);
```

You should be able to just change `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH`

i.e

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener enterListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
           if ((keyEvent != null && (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)) {
               new DownloadTask().execute();
               return true; 
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

recherche.setOnEditorActionListener(enterListener);
```

--Edit--

Make sure you have imported KeyEvent and onEditorActionListener

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
```

Comment: may be a silly question but have you imported KeyEvent?  import android.view.KeyEvent;

Comment: He will not answer you because you are commenting on your answer not his question :)